# Python Enum Equality Performance

Tags: python, enums

Enum datatypes are good abstractions for enumerable datatype like days of week, months etc. Nevertheless the simplest tests show that we pay 2.5 slower performance for such datatypes. Do we have any explanation for such behavior?

Consider two simple enums in Python

```
import enum
import timeit

class IntDow(enum.Enum):
    MONDAY=enum.auto()
    TUESDAY=enum.auto()
    WEDNESDAY=enum.auto()
    THURSDAY=enum.auto()
    FRIDAY=enum.auto()
    SATURDAY=enum.auto()
    SUNDAY=enum.auto()
    
class StrDow(str, enum.Enum):
    MONDAY="MONDAY"
    TUESDAY="TUESDAY"
    WEDNESDAY="WEDNESDAY"
    THURSDAY="THURSDAY"
    FRIDAY="FRIDAY"
    SATURDAY="SATURDAY"
    SUNDAY="SUNDAY"
    
int_mon = IntDow["MONDAY"]
int_tue = IntDow["TUESDAY"]
str_mon = StrDow["MONDAY"]
str_tue = StrDow["TUESDAY"]
raw_mon = "MONDAY"
raw_tue = "TUESDAY"
```

and carry out the simplest equality tests

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: int_mon == IntDow.MONDAY, number=100000)
0.017555099999299273
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: int_mon == int_tue, number=100000)
0.00824300000022049
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: int_mon == IntDow.TUESDAY, number=100000)
0.018771999999444233
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: str_mon == StrDow.MONDAY, number=100000)
0.01836639999964973
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: str_mon == StrDow.TUESDAY, number=100000)
0.01744440000038594
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: str_mon == str_tue, number=100000)
0.007430400000885129
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: raw_mon == "MONDAY", number=100000)
0.007222599999295198
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: raw_mon == "TUESDAY", number=100000)
0.00726819999908912
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: raw_mon == raw_tue, number=100000)
0.007780600000842242
```

We can see that variable to constant comparison for `enum` is approximately 2.5 times slower than for `str`. Do we have any explanation for such behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bulk of the extra time is not spent in the equality test, but in looking up the member from the enum (i.e. `IntDow.MONDAY`).  In those cases where performance is critical, export the members from the enum first:

```
MONDAY, TUESDAY, ... = IntDow
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.